# Relational Table insert

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I have ManyToOne relation of two entities

```
@Entity(name = "foo")
public class Foo {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "fooId")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            targetEntity = Bar.class,
            cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinColumn(name = "foo")
    private Set<Bar> bars;

    public Foo() {
        bars = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public Set<Bar> getBars() {
        return bars;
    }

    public void setBars(Set<Bar> bars) {
        this.bars = bars;
    }

}

@Entity(name = "bar")
public class Bar {

    @Column(name = "fooId")
    private Foo foo;

    public Bar() {}

}

public class Persist {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPersistUnit")
    private EntityManager manager;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo f = new Foo();
        f.getBars().add(new Bar());

        manager.persist(f);
    }
}
```

But when i call the Hibernate persist method, the Foo entity is saved sucessfull, but with Bar entity i got not-null violation in field foo;

Can somebody tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: You're missing the rest of your code. There's no reasonable way to answer this without seeing the actual code involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set Foo entity reference in Bar Entity . It will solve your problem

```
    Foo f = new Foo();
    Bar bar=new Bar();
    bar.setFoo(f);
    f.getBars().add(bar);
    manager.persist(f);
```